# SPMetal ignores lookup columns in Farm Solution

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have content types and related lists (via lookup columns) in a **Sandbox** solution(wsp). All my lookup column relationships come up fine in the SPMetal generated entity classes.

I now have a requirement to change the solution **from Sandbox to Farm** scope.
However, once I change the solution from SandBox to Farm scope and deploy it, and then run SPMetal on my lists, it no longer generates navigation properties for my lookup columns.
They just have a property for the Id of the lookup column and not the actual object.

Can anyone shed some light on why SPMetal ignores my lookup columns when the wsp is changed from SandBox to Farm scope???

Answer (score 0):

to my knowledge SPMetal doesn't generate complete lookup classes on its own. You have to do some extra work to make this functional. Don't know why it worked in your previous settings...